# Aligning headings correctly whilst merging multiple text files

Tags: r, excel, linux, bash

I have multiple text files (~4,200 files, each file ~14kb) that contain output data from a machine with most files containing 593 headers e.g. DOB, Time of visit, date of visit + other data outputs. However, some text files contain only some of the headers but others are missing. The headers in all the files share the same names. I would like to combine all the text files into one file such that all data aligns under the correct header. I wonder if anybody could please suggest how to do this and which program to use - thank you in advance!

Any help where to start would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: In response to "I wonder if anybody could please suggest how to do this and which program to use" - that would be trivial using AWK. In response to "Any help where to start would greatly be appreciated!" - get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robins and search this forum for answers to similar problems.

Comment: You don't show a sketch of how the individual files look like (for instance, how a header is defined), so it is hared to recommend anything. Also you specify r, excel and bash, and I wonder what you want to achieve with this mix, in particular since AFIK has not yet released an Excel version which would run on Linux (which you also mention).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an R example.  TLDR `dplyr::bind_rows()` will do the work for you.

```r
## create data
tdir <- tempdir()
x1 <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b=2:4)
x2 <- data.frame(a = 4:6, c=5:7)

x1
#>   a b
#> 1 1 2
#> 2 2 3
#> 3 3 4
x2
#>   a c
#> 1 4 5
#> 2 5 6
#> 3 6 7

## export to temporary directory
rio::export(x1, paste0(tdir, "/x1.txt"))
rio::export(x2, paste0(tdir, "/x2.txt"))

## list files
lf <- list.files(tdir, pattern="txt$", full.names = TRUE)

## read in all data
dats <- lapply(lf, rio::import)

## bind together
alldat <- dplyr::bind_rows(dats, .id="file")
alldat
#>   file a  b  c
#> 1    1 1  2 NA
#> 2    1 2  3 NA
#> 3    1 3  4 NA
#> 4    2 4 NA  5
#> 5    2 5 NA  6
#> 6    2 6 NA  7
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>